# How to convert Curl to Python request code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, curl, converters

I want to make a curl to python converter.

```
curl -X POST -H "data1:value1" -H "data2:value2" -d "{"datapart1":"random1","datapart2":"random2"}" "https://example.com"'
```

And i want to convert:

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com'

data = '{"datapart1":"random1","datapart2":"random2"}'

headers = {'data1': 'value1', 'data2': 'value2'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Great! Sounds like you want `shlex.split()` to split the `curl` command line to parts like the shell does, and then continue from there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this https://formatter.xyz/curl-to-python-converter

you try it that

Comment: This site submits your curl commands to their server. They could be saving your curl commands. curl commands can contain cookies and other sensitive information if you copied them [from the browser](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas) or someone sent you a command. I wouldn't use this.

Comment: Also, the OP is asking how to implement this himself, not for a website that does it.

Comment: Also that site is useless as it cannot even handle `-F` parameters, looks like a honeypot